# How to find the cardinality of the neighborhood 2-change of TSP?

Tags: traveling-salesman

Consider the TSP problem. Let $F_n=\{\text{all cyclic permutations $\pi$ on $n$ objects} \}$. Define the neighborhood 2-change of TSP as

$$N_2^n(f)=\{g: g\in F_n \text{ and $g$ can be obtained from $f$ as follows:}\\ \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\;\;\;\; \text{remove two edges from the tour; then}\\ \quad­\quad\quad\quad\quad\;\, \text{replace them with two edges}\}.$$

What is the cardinality of $N_2^n(f)$?

I start with few examples like $N_2^1(f)=0$, $N_2^2(f)=0$, $N_2^3(f)=3$ but I cannot find it in general.

Comment: A suggestion: keep computing for a few more values of $n$ ($n=4,5,6$), then look the sequence up in the OEIS.  You should be able to compute it for small values of $n$ by writing a program to exhaustively enumerate all the cases.

Comment: But I think there should be a closed-form formula for it, no?